# Model Get GrandParent

Tags: laravel

I have the following models in my application:

1. Cab
2. Destination
3. Passenger

Where:

- Cab has many destinations
- Cab has many passengers
- Destination has many cabs
- Destination has many passengers
- Passenger has one cab
- Passenger has one destination

Now I am trying to run a query that returns the list of all cabs along with their destinations and the number of passengers going to each destination and the total no of passengers in the car:

```php
Cab::withCount(["passengers" => function($q) {
    return $query->whereNull("expired_at");
}])
->when($withDestinations, function ($query) use ($status) {
    return $query->whereHas("destinations")
        ->with(["destinations" => function ($query) {
            return $query->whereHas("passengers", function ($query) {
                return $query->whereNull("expired_at");
            })->withCount("passengers");
        }]);
})
->paginate(25)
```

Now the problem here is for some reason it returns passengers for a destination but it does not filter the query by cab_id.

These are my models:

**cab.php**:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Cab extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ["arrived_at", "departed_at", "suspended_at", "deleted_at"];

    public function company() {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Models\Company", "company_id");
    }

    public function driver() {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Models\Driver", "driver_id");
    }

    public function status() {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Models\Status", "status_id");
    }

    public function destinations() {
        return $this->belongsToMany("App\Models\Destination", 'destination_cab', 'cab_id', 'destination_id');
    }

    public function passengers() {
        return $this->hasMany("App\Models\Passenger", "cab_id");
    }

    public function photo() {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Models\Resource", "photo_id");
    }
}
```

**destination.php**:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Destination extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ["suspended_at", "deleted_at"];

    public function company() {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Models\Company", "company_id");
    }

    public function cabs() {
        return $this->belongsToMany("App\Models\Cab", "destination_cab", "destination_id", "cab_id");
    }

    public function passengers() {
        return $this->hasMany("App\Models\Passenger", "destination_id");
    }
}
```

**passenger.php**:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Passenger extends Model
{

    protected $dates = ["due_at", "expired_at"];

    protected $casts = ["meta" => "json"];

    protected $fillable = ["meta"];

}
```

Comment: I don't see bus_id anywhere in the above code. did you mean cab_id? `but it does not filter the query by bus_id`

Comment: Yh sorry about that, dunno how that got in there, have edited my post.